# Gradle build fail: Read timed out and jcenter

Tags: java, gradle

I created a new Gradle project today in IntelliJ and couldn't build it, every time it failed with this error:

```
   > Could not resolve org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.17.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:2.6.5 > org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.6.5
      > Could not resolve org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.17.
         > Could not get resource 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.17/spring-core-5.3.17.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory/jcenter/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.17/spring-core-5.3.17.pom'.
               > Read timed out
```

Since the reported URL contains 'jcenter' in it, I'm wondering if the failure it related to [JCenter shutdown](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown). I couldn't explain how it happened since I use `mavenCentral` repository.
This is my very simple build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.sample'
version = '1.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I tried to open https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.17/spring-core-5.3.17.pom in browser, HTTP 303 was returned + location = https://repo.gradle.org/artifactory/jcenter/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.17/spring-core-5.3.17.pom .

Does anyone face the same issue?

Comment: This started recently. It affects other users as well. see: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/received-status-code-524-from-server-origin-time-out/42526

Comment: Should be working again.

Comment: Yeah, working again now.